# VB.NET application. Create a Solidworks session using CreateObject and .UserControl = True but the session is not 100% usable for the user

Tags: vb.net, solidworks, createobject

I tried many things and searched a lot on the web and on this site, but I could not find a solution.
I have a problems which is:

I'm making an application in VB.NET that connects to Solidworks.

**Case 1**:
Solidworks is running.

- `swApp.CreateObject ("SldWorks.Application") / swApp.UserControl = True / swApp.Visible = True`
- Double click on solidworks file (part, assembly or drawing) = solidworks opens the document in the current session.

Case 2:
Solidworks is not running.

- `swApp.CreateObject ("SldWorks.Application") / swApp.UserControl = True / swApp.Visible = True`
- Double click on solidworks file (part, assembly or drawing) = solidworks does NOT open the document.

Case 2 produces a solidworks session useful for my application, but not for the user. I want to make case 2 behave like the case 1. Any suggestions?

From already thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that worked for me:
Looking at the Windows Task Manager I realized that the problem can be overcome by opening a solidworks file (ex: .sldprt)... not Soliworks.exe directly: `Process.Start("path of some solidworks file")` and then wait for the process "swShellFileLauncher.exe" ceases before using `swApp.CreateObject("SldWorks.Application")`

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that comes to mind is in one scenario Solidworks may be running with elevated permissions and it affects its behaviour, [here's how you can check](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-as-administrator-elevated-in-windows/).

In practice I'd suggest you to check for case 2 (sw process is not running) in your vb.net app and start it with Process.Start() and only then connect with CreateObject(), effectively converting case 2 into case 1.

Comment: Thanks Vlad!
Following your suggestion I found that Solidworks is not running with elevated permissions.
The solution you propose is the one I am using, but it has a problem, I must use a timer or pause because Solidworks must be fully loaded before using CreateObject or we will be on scenario 1 again.

Comment: here's what you can do to force solidworks to always start as administrator
https://superuser.com/a/468056. 

Do it for SLDWORKS.exe instead of devenv.exe